# Laravel Passport vs JWT-auth for Android

Tags: laravel

I want my users to be able to access my **Laravel application** from their mobile app (Android/IOS).

The application has authentication, as laravel requires CSRF in forms so I decided to use REST API. After searching I've found Laravel Passport, JWT-auth. (I don't need to use anything like Oauth, socialite).

As I dig into JWT-auth, I found anyone having "token" can access to user accounts that is very much risky.

What should I do?  Is there any way I can request to server from mobile application for CSRF Token and send it to the server while requesting authentication. (My input fields are static to the mobile app)

Comment: You can only get the token after supplying the username/password first then you save the token to private storage to keep the user logged-in & request other end-points; And you may add a logout button in your app so there's nothing risky as long as you are communicating over https

Comment: But if some one else can access user's token then he may be able to access the user account which is terrifying. In that case what should I do, to protect my users?

Comment: each user has his own token, he can get the token after logging in with the username/password combination in android you store the token in a secure storage & you are communicating over https; what's insecure about it? you may add something into your application to regenerate the token every x hours if you are too keen on security

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot!